# Locale not available in PostgreSQL 9.6 on Jelastic 5.4

Tags: postgresql, locale, jelastic

I have an automated deployment procedure, based on bash scripts, that creates a database on a PostgreSQL node on a Jelastic environment. My provider is using version 5.4 of the Jelastic platform.

The automated procedure has been used dozens of times successfully, but it refuses to run today.

My older Jelastic environments all have PostgreSQL version 9.4.x or 9.5.x. However, a new environment that I just created gave me version 9.6.x, which seems to be (according to the environment topology screen) the only PostgreSQL version available on the 9.x branch.

The following statement is no longer working with PostgreSQL version 9.6.x:

```
createdb -T template0 -E UTF8 -l es_EC.UTF-8 -U webadmin -w -e <database-name>
```

Of course, `<database-name>` is the name of the database I intend to create. I get the following error message:

> createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  invalid locale name:
>   "es_EC.UTF-8"

I have not tested my application with PostgreSQL v10.x and do not have the opportunity to do so now. Please let me know what you suggest that I do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The 9.6 database is probably being installed on a machine that doesn't have that locale installed.

PostgreSQL uses the operating system locales, so you can run `locale -a` on the shell to see all installed locales.

All you probably need to do is to install the desired locale on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Locales of base image of PostgreSQL and other templates were removed knowingly in order to decrease total size of docker image. At the same time, user is able to install locale manually with help of using [SSH access](https://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-access):

```
sudo localedef -v -c -i es_EC -f UTF-8 es_EC.UTF-8
```

Note: after [container redeploy](https://docs.jelastic.com/container-redeploy) locales will be returned to its initial state. In order to overcome this limitation you can specify the provided command in [run command](https://docs.jelastic.com/container-run-configuration)

Comment: Please clarify whether the "container redeploy" that you mention would also happen when the environment is restarted, either via the stop/start button that is available for each environment or when performing a manual deployment of a new WAR, which forces a restart of the Tomcat node (in the latter case, I believe the PostgreSQL node is unaffected.) At this point, by myself I do not use directly or explicitly any container-related operations on my environments, other than what Jelastic might perform internally as part of the operations I mentioned above (environment restart and WAR redeploy.)